# Load external webpage into div

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe, external

I have been reading about iframe, jquery, jsonp and what not how to come up with a solution to my "problem".

I am wondering, what is the best approach to get the result I need?

Any and ALL help with this is greatly appreciated!
Suggestion code/script/strings is prefered, I have never tried something like this before.

Scenario:

- Load/display external URL/webpage from external.com/loadme.html to domain.com/loaded.html
- Possible to navigate (click links) in the loaded/iframed output

I am wondering, how should I go about making the external.com/loadme.html?

- using ajax for navigation and loading content into the loadme.html?
- Regular navigation links?

Basicly, I am going to make a page with some content, a couple of links and what not, and load the whole thing to 2 other websites with navigation and all, inside a DIV.

I am not sure what would be the best way to do this, and before I use alot of time researching this, I wanted to ask if someone have any suggestions?

Thanks!!
-Tom

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with an `iframe`? It does all of this work for you.

Comment: Nothing wrong with an iframe ;p just wondering if I could do this more "smoothly" with loading and whatever.. As I said,, I have never done anything like this before..

Answer (score 0):

If this is across multiple domains, you will more than likely need to use iFrames anyways.

Comment: It is across multiple domains.. I read something about JSONP and multiple domains, ajax and what not. Basicly, I am looking for the best possible way to display the external content, with a clean and simple user experience.

Comment: JSONP is just a data format. If you want to load an actual webpage from another domain, an iframe is your *only* solution. (Well, you can use AJAX if you can configure the external server to accept requests for it, but that's probably more trouble than it's worth.)